# Text field not deleting the data when i press `X` button in keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have 4 `UItextfield` for enter the top number. Like 1 2 3 4. When I enter the top number in my all text field, and if I am in last urtext field - and if I press backward button or x key in my key board - My number are in each text field are not getting deleted. I was not able to delete.

Here is my code :

```
  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let value = textField.text!
        let length = value.characters.count
        if (length == 1) {
            return false
        }
        if (textField == Field1) {
            self.performSelector(Selector("setNextResponder:"), withObject: Field2, afterDelay: 0.2)
            textField1 = string
        } else  if (textField == Field2) {
            self.performSelector(Selector("setNextResponder:"), withObject: Field3, afterDelay: 0.2)
            textField2 = string
        } else if (textField == Field3) {
            self.performSelector(Selector("setNextResponder:"), withObject: Field4, afterDelay: 0.2)
            textField3 = string
        } else if (textField == Field4) {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            textField4 = string
            nextButton.enabled = true
        }

     else  if (textField == Field4)
 {
     if string == "" && textField.text?.characters.count == 1 {
            Field1.text = ""
            Field2.text = ""
            Field3.text = ""
            Field4.text = ""
            Field1.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }


        return true
    }
```

What i am missing?

Comment: i couldn't understand what you are asking for ? X key in keyboard or the one in textfield to clear the text ?

Comment: When back button is pressed, does the first responder change accordingly?

Comment: Actually i have 4 uitext field. for enter the otp number.When i in last uitext field and if i press `x` delete button in keyboard measn its not going back to each text field

Comment: Question not clear, can you please provide more info on this problem?

Comment: See, actually i will enter one one value in my four uitext field.So when i am in last uitext field. And if i want to cancel all value means .By using keyboard and if i press `x` key in keyboard to go back and delete my value means, its not working

Comment: for one text field , its getting delete..But what i need is , if i am in textfield 4 measn then if i press delete button - it have to go to textfild 3,2,1 and should delete all data

Comment: @user5513630 if you want to clear all textfield value you should create a custom method, or may set rightview in last textfield, it will not be done with default method

Comment: @Pyro  can you please explain with some code exmaple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

if textField.text?.characters.count == 1 && string == "" {
    if textField == txt2 {
        txt2.text = ""
        txt1.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == txt3 {
        txt3.text = ""
        txt2.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == txt4 {
        txt4.text = ""
        txt3.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
return true
```

}

Still if possible you should create a separate button with `clearText` action to clear all textfield instead of clearing the textfield from the clear button. It will look as better UI/UX as per the default iOS clear button behaviour

Comment: When i am in last text field, And if i press `x` key - it doesn't go back

Comment: @user5513630 what you mean by go back? the current code clears all the textfield when you clear the 4th textfield(length = 0), if you want to clear on every 'x' remove the length condition

Comment: i tried your code,If i clear 4 th text field also - my all text field data are not getting clear

Comment: you want me to upload that method of `shouldChangeCharacterInRange` and should i add your code too??? or just my old code

Comment: your solution code is directly going to first text field , when i am in 4th text field.

Comment: but when i am in 4 th text field and if i press 'X' then it have to go to 3 rd text field and 4th text field shold be empty. Same like when i am in 3rd text field and if i press 'x' key it have to go to 2nd text field and 3rd text field should be empty

Comment: @user5513630 so you want that for every textfield, i thought on clear of textfield 4 you want to clear all textfield and move to textfield 1 directly

Comment: Yes, what i need is : user have to go each each text field and the value should delete and should go back

Comment: Din Get you dude??

Comment: @user5513630 yes, it's possible

Comment: Yes, thats what i am asking some example code to work

Comment: @user5513630 updated the code, replace the whole method and try

Comment: because, by starting when i enter my value in all text field. it has to do forward.If i press 'X' in my last text field.It have to go backward one by one

Comment: yes and only when the last character is there in current textfield

Comment: Still, its going till 3rd text field but if i press 'X' key -when i am in 3rd text field.Its not going back to 2nd, 1st.   Really from morning i am facing same problem ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109711/discussion-between-pyro-and-user5513630).

Comment: So does you issue resolved with my new code or from your changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.text = ""
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}
```

Also choose an appropriate option from attribute inspector.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution.But i don't want the editing appear when i enter the value. So when i am in last uitext field. And if i want to cancel all value means .By using keyboard and if i press `x` key in keyboard to go back and delete my value means, its not working

Comment: I think u got to have a wrong logic on OTP.  I suggest you to follow to activate the second TextField only if the first TextField condition is satisfied. You can follow the same pattern for the second, third  and fourth. ie, The fourth textfield must be enabled after previous three textfield conditions are correct.

Comment: How can i check with my otp itself in all text field

Comment: Suppose you have  a Forgot to Password ViewController. The three Textfields are "Old Password', "New Password", "Confirm Password" and a Button "Submit".  You must be verifying the text Entered in each TextField using validation and API response check. You can follow the pattern in which TextFields are enabled one by one satisfying conditions.

Comment: oh, this condition i am checking at last when i press the submit button .But my client need , when i press `x` key in keyboard - it should go back to delete the all value in all text field

Comment: Thats sounds not fair. I suggest you to follow a standard way of User Experience. Another option is to save the four TextField's Value to different Strings and clear those when user press X , reassign as textfields text. That might help you.